# Multiprocessing function not writing to file or printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, python-multiprocessing

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi (3 B+) making a data collection device and I'm 
trying to spawn a process to record the data coming in and write it to a file. I have a function for the writing that works fine when I call it directly.

When I call it using the multiprocess approach however, nothing seems to happen. I can see in task monitors in Linux that the process does in fact get spawned but no file gets written, and when I try to pass a flag to it to shut down it doesn't work, meaning I end up terminating the process and nothing seems to have happened.

I've been over this every which way and can't see what I'm doing wrong; does anyone else? In case it's relevant, these are functions inside a parent class, and one of the functions is meant to spawn another as a thread.

Code I'm using:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv
from drivers.IMU_SEN0 import IMU_SEN0
import multiprocessing, os

class IMU_data_logger:
    _output_filename = ''
    _csv_headers = []
    _accelerometer_headers = ['Accelerometer X','Accelerometer    Y','Accelerometer Z']
    _gyroscope_headers = ['Gyroscope X','Gyroscope Y','Gyroscope Z']
    _magnetometer_headers = ['Bearing']
    _log_accelerometer = False
    _log_gyroscope= False
    _log_magnetometer = False
    IMU = None
    _writer=[]
    _run_underway = False
    _process=[]
    _stop_value = 0

def __init__(self,output_filename='/home/pi/blah.csv',log_accelerometer = True,log_gyroscope= True,log_magnetometer = True):
    """data logging device
    NOTE! Multiple instances of this class should not use the same IMU devices simultaneously!"""        
    self._output_filename = output_filename
    self._log_accelerometer = log_accelerometer
    self._log_gyroscope = log_gyroscope
    self._log_magnetometer = log_magnetometer

def __del__(self):
    # TODO Update this
    if self._run_underway: # If there's still a run underway, end it first
        self.end_recording()

def _set_up(self):        
    self.IMU = IMU_SEN0(self._log_accelerometer,self._log_gyroscope,self._log_magnetometer)
    self._set_up_headers()

def _set_up_headers(self):
    """Set up the headers of the CSV file based on the header substrings at top and the input flags on what will be measured"""
    self._csv_headers = []
    if self._log_accelerometer is not None:
        self._csv_headers+= self._accelerometer_headers
    if self._log_gyroscope is not None:
        self._csv_headers+= self._gyroscope_headers
    if self._log_magnetometer is not None:
        self._csv_headers+= self._magnetometer_headers


def _record_data(self,frequency,stop_value):
    self._set_up() #Run setup in thread

    """Record data function, which takes a recording frequency, in herz, as an input"""
    previous_read_time=datetime.now()-timedelta(1,0,0)
    self._run_underway = True # Note that a run is now going
    Period = 1/frequency # Period, in seconds, of a recording based on the input frequency
    print("Writing output data to",self._output_filename)

    with open(self._output_filename,'w',newline='') as outcsv:
        self._writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
        self._writer.writerow(self._csv_headers) # Write headers to file

        while stop_value.value==0: # While a run continues
            if datetime.now()-previous_read_time>=timedelta(0,1,0): # If we've waited a period, collect the data; otherwise keep looping
                print("run underway value",self._run_underway)
            if datetime.now()-previous_read_time>=timedelta(0,Period,0): # If we've waited a period, collect the data; otherwise keep looping
                previous_read_time = datetime.now() # Update previous readtime
                next_row = []
                if self._log_accelerometer:
                    # Get values in m/s^2
                    axes = self.IMU.read_accelerometer_values()
                    next_row += [axes['x'],axes['y'],axes['z']]

                if self._log_gyroscope:
                    # Read gyro values
                    gyro = self.IMU.read_gyroscope_values()
                    next_row += [gyro['x'],gyro['y'],gyro['z']]

                if self._log_magnetometer:
                    # Read magnetometer value
                    b= self.IMU.read_magnetometer_bearing()
                    next_row += b

                self._writer.writerow(next_row)

        # Close the csv when done
        outcsv.close()

def start_recording(self,frequency_in_hz):        
    # Create recording process
    self._stop_value = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)
    self._process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._record_data,args=(frequency_in_hz,self._stop_value))

    # Start recording process
    self._process.start()
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"),"Data logging process spawned")
    print("Logging Accelerometer:",self._log_accelerometer)
    print("Logging Gyroscope:",self._log_gyroscope)
    print("Logging Magnetometer:",self._log_magnetometer)     
    print("ID of data logging process: {}".format(self._process.pid))

def end_recording(self,terminate_wait = 2):
    """Function to end the recording multithread that's been spawned.
    Args: terminate_wait: This is the time, in seconds, to wait after attempting to shut down the process before terminating it."""
    # Get process id
    id = self._process.pid

    # Set stop event for process
    self._stop_value.value = 1

    self._process.join(terminate_wait) # Wait two seconds for the process to terminate
    if self._process.is_alive(): # If it's still alive after waiting
        self._process.terminate()
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"),"Process",id,"needed to be terminated.")
    else:
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"),"Process",id,"successfully ended itself.")
```

====================================================================

**ANSWER**: For anyone following up here, it turns out the problem was my use of the VS Code debugger which apparently doesn't work with multiprocessing and was somehow preventing the success of the spawned process. Many thanks to Tomasz Swider below for helping me work through issues and, eventually, find my idiocy. The help was very deeply appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few thing wrong in your code:

First thing 
stop_value == 0 will not work as the multiprocess.Value('i', 0) != 0, change that line to

```
while stop_value.value == 0
```

Second, you never update previous_read_time so it will write the readings as fast as it can, you will run out of disk quick

Third, try use time.sleep() the thing you are doing is called busy looping and it is bad, it is wasting CPU cycles needlessly.

Four, terminating with self._stop_value = 1 probably will not work there must be other way to set that value maybe self._stop_value.value = 1.

Well here is a pice of example code based on the code that you have provided that is working just fine:

```
import csv
import multiprocessing
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint


class IMU(object):

    @staticmethod
    def read_accelerometer_values():
        return dict(x=randint(0, 100), y=randint(0, 100), z=randint(0, 10))


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, output_filename):
        self._output_filename = output_filename
        self._csv_headers = ['xxxx','y','z']
        self._log_accelerometer = True
        self.IMU = IMU()

    def _record_data(self, frequency, stop_value):
        #self._set_up()  # Run setup functions for the data collection device and store it in the self.IMU variable

        """Record data function, which takes a recording frequency, in herz, as an input"""
        previous_read_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(1, 0, 0)
        self._run_underway = True  # Note that a run is now going
        Period = 1 / frequency  # Period, in seconds, of a recording based on the input frequency
        print("Writing output data to", self._output_filename)

        with open(self._output_filename, 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
            self._writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
            self._writer.writerow(self._csv_headers)  # Write headers to file

            while stop_value.value == 0:  # While a run continues
                if datetime.now() - previous_read_time >= timedelta(0, 1,
                                                                    0):  # If we've waited a period, collect the data; otherwise keep looping
                    print("run underway value", self._run_underway)
                if datetime.now() - previous_read_time >= timedelta(0, Period,
                                                                    0):  # If we've waited a period, collect the data; otherwise keep looping
                    next_row = []
                    if self._log_accelerometer:
                        # Get values in m/s^2
                        axes = self.IMU.read_accelerometer_values()
                        next_row += [axes['x'], axes['y'], axes['z']]

                    previous_read_time = datetime.now()
                    self._writer.writerow(next_row)

            # Close the csv when done
            outcsv.close()

    def start_recording(self, frequency_in_hz):
        # Create recording process
        self._stop_value = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
        self._process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._record_data, args=(frequency_in_hz, self._stop_value))

        # Start recording process
        self._process.start()
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), "Data logging process spawned")
        print("ID of data logging process: {}".format(self._process.pid))

    def end_recording(self, terminate_wait=2):
        """Function to end the recording multithread that's been spawned.
        Args: terminate_wait: This is the time, in seconds, to wait after attempting to shut down the process before terminating it."""
        # Get process id
        id = self._process.pid

        # Set stop event for process
        self._stop_value.value = 1

        self._process.join(terminate_wait)  # Wait two seconds for the process to terminate
        if self._process.is_alive():  # If it's still alive after waiting
            self._process.terminate()
            print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), "Process", id, "needed to be terminated.")
        else:
            print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), "Process", id, "successfully ended itself.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo('/tmp/foometer.csv')
    foo.start_recording(20)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Ending recording')
    foo.end_recording()
```

Comment: First two points are great catches; I've corrected them in my actual code, thanks!

I'm confused about why time.sleep() is better though. I'd actually read in a few other cases that this was a particularly bad approach for data collection as it leaves you to the mercies of the OS task management and increases the chances that you'll miss a data collection. I'd rather waste CPU cycles than miss data.

I'll try self._stop_value.value=1 on the fourth point.

Comment: Another followup; I implemented the suggested changes (1,2, and 4) but the original issue of nothing being written remains. :-/ Fixes incorporated in the original question above as well; to my mind it looks like it should work as is, but still doesn't.

Comment: You need to post more code, When I am running an example composed from the code that you have posted it is working just fine. The problem has to be in the calling code. For example what does the _set_up() do ?

Comment: Added the _set_up() code; there's not much else to add other than the init, the headers set up (which basically just creates a string), and the destructor. The only other thing that I see immediately between my code and yours is that you initiate the IMU in the init, whereas I did so in _set_up (previously it was earlier but I wondered if I needed to do this in the spawned thread). Is there something there that could be breaking this?

Comment: The self._set_up() call in your example is not indented correctly so this is not exact code you are running. 
In python you are not supposed to create instance variables in methods other than __init__ so I would remove the _set_up() completely. One more important thing you are not starting a thread it is a process you are starting, It is a very big difference. Another thing your program might be hangin in the  IMU_0140() call so you would need to post that to. But if I were you this kind of thing is very easy to debug when you have all the code.

Comment: Simplest approach is to put print statements between every lines in the _record_data() and see where does it stop. My bet is on the _set_up(). Second thing is to get a decent IDE eg Pycharm Community (free) with decent debugger that is able for follow forks.  
Third thing you could do as you say that the process is actually starting. Use py-spy to check on what it is doing, https://github.com/benfred/py-spy. Another thing you could use strace https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace to see the system calls that are sent. Sorry for ranting, I need a cofe.

Comment: No apologies needed; your ranting about my problem is awesome! I've replaced the samples above with the entire code. Any spacing issues you see are a result of the StackOverflow code logging thing; in the original they're fine.

Comment: I've been using VS Code which for some reason isn't allowing me to debug into the process (would support that _set_up() fails), I'm concerned that Pycharm is too resource intensive to run on the Raspberry Pi and I don't have a non-Pi environment with all the packages installed. Will try the print statements thing; still don't understand why it would work when called normally but not when called as a multiprocess.

Comment: I see, How much RAM do you have on the raspberry ? Every python process will take 50 MB of RAM. Maybe you actually want to use threads instead of processes. Is there a reason for process over threads ?

Comment: I was under the impression that the python multiprocessing module was basically a wrapper over threads except avoiding some of the lock problems that python threading functionality can suffer from. That was the basis of this choice. I take it then that the reason for the lack of action from the process isn't apparent from the above?

Comment: Oh, and the Pi has 1 gig of ram so should be more than enough for this purpose, but it's slow enough even using VS Code that I'm hesitant to try for Pycharm, which even on my main computer is an order of magnitude slower as it indexes everything.

Comment: Yes I would not run pycharm on something with 1G of RAM :). Multiprocessing starts a separate process, so it is separate instance of python interpreter, whereas thread will run in one process. Usually threads are used for IO bound things and processes for computation, as they can run on more than one CPU, but Raspberry probably has only one CPU anway.

Comment: Also, I added print statements to the _set_up() code and as before, nothing gets printed. I even added a print statement as the first line of the function to be spawned and nothing comes of it.

Comment: What is the python version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186011/discussion-between-j-natael-and-tomasz-swider).